# Gitlab Debian Package

Tags: software-installation, gitlab

I need to install GitLab in my ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Found the following [link](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/1094) but it doesn't work for me.

We need it to be a debian package to simplify installation in my company network

I know there is a [bitnami](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/1094) installer but I don't like it (no trust with 3rd party)

Note: I don't want to accumulate scripts! I need a simple install one-click

GitLab is the ultimate git server manager for local networks and private companies

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can just not found what you do need...

if you wish to give a try. This [tutorial](http://blog.compunet.co.za/gitlab-installation-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/) is great for you.

Also, you can check this [script](https://gist.github.com/cristianrasch/2440768),it may help....

Comment: nice try, but I need a debian package

Answer (score 2):

**New solution:**

```
sudo apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
dpkg -i gitlab-ce-XXX.deb
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

**Old answer:**

There is a debian package available for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit at [www.gitlab.com/downloads](https://www.gitlab.com/downloads/). There you can also find Virtual Machine Images with GitLab.