# GitLab dpkg-buildpackage error

Tags: dpkg, compiling, gitlab

This is a question related to [my other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395293/gitlab-debian-package)

I am following [these instructions](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/1094) to build a Debian package out of gitlab management software. I got the following error

```
dpkg-buildpackage
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin:
vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
-Wformat-security dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin:
vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
-Wformat-security dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 dpkg-buildpackage: export
LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor):
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro tail: cannot open `debian/changelog' for reading: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: tail of debian/changelog gave error exit
status 1
```

Any help with the above errors

Comment: Please elaborate on what Debian/Ubuntu packaging source you are using. The [Gitlab software source](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) does not contain any `debian/` directory so it's not suitable to be built like this. The pull request you refer to isn't merged. In case you need the source from the pull request, check out the author's fork. It's outdated, of course.

Comment: You are right, I just tried to download the source directly from master repository and issued the commands on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be running `dpkg-buildpackage` from inside the `debian/` directory.  You should be running it from the top-level directory.

If that's not the case, make sure the `debian/` directory exists at all.

Update: 
By the way, Gitlab is not suitable to be built with Debian so your command `dpkg-buildpackage` will never work...

Comment: I created a directory named debian and inside it I created a file named changelog. the new error is   parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l0): found eof where expected first heading
parsechangelog/debian: error: fatal error occurred while parsing input
dpkg-buildpackage: error: changelog parser /usr/lib/dpkg/parsechangelog/debian gave error exit status 255

Comment: I will consider your note as the answer because I found that what I am trying to do is not applicable. I will try another situation

Answer (score 0):

dpkg-buildpackage: error: ... error exit status 255

can be caused by debian/* files EOL becoming \r\n (Windows EOL) rather than \r (Unix EOL)
Running dos2unix on the appropriate files fixed this error for me.